# (C#) Popup of grid appear on buttons tap

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have this xaml code on one of the windows in my app:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="panoramaItemSend" Header="{Binding LocalizedResources.send, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" >
            <StackPanel Margin="12,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.recipientEmail, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"  />
                <TextBox InputScope="EmailUserName" Text="{Binding SendModel.Email, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="-12,0,0,0" TabIndex="100" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" MaxLength="256" Height="105" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <prismInteractivity:UpdateTextBindingOnPropertyChanged/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBox>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.amount, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="txtSendAmount" InputScope="Number" Text="{Binding SendModel.Amount, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="-12,0,0,0" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" TabIndex="101" MaxLength="20" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" >
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <prismInteractivity:UpdateTextBindingOnPropertyChanged/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SendModel.AmountFiatStr}" Margin="0,-15,0,5" Foreground="Gainsboro"/>


                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.label, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding SendModel.Label, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="-12,0,0,0" TabIndex="102" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" MaxLength="256">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <prismInteractivity:UpdateTextBindingOnPropertyChanged/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBox>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.message, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
                <TextBox  Text="{Binding SendModel.Message, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="-12,0,0,0" TabIndex="103" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" MaxLength="256">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <prismInteractivity:UpdateTextBindingOnPropertyChanged/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBox>
                <Button x:Name="btnSend" Content="{Binding LocalizedResources.send, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Style="{StaticResource OrangeButton}" Tap="btnSend_Tap" TabIndex="104"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

I want to create a popup when I trigger btnSend's Tap handler - btnSendTap
My popup should have this grid full of accounts that I already know how to add programatically:

```
<Grid Margin="15,0,0,21">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="AccountsInfo" Grid.Row="0">
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                        <local:RateChart x:Name="rateChart" Height="324" Margin="-12,25,0,0" Width="417" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [PopUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842) control.

Hope that is what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Thanks :) It is what i am looking for